# How can I bind my click function to my button in KnockoutJS?

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, telegram

In the code below you can see that I'm trying to add a click-event on my button which I'm creating dynamically in JavaScript with data-bind:"click: replay". But it seems like the code isn't executing the click function. However when I create manually a button in HTML, the click event do work.

```
var GeneralTelegram = function(){

    var self = this;

    app_socket_handler = function(data) {
        switch (data.action) {
            case "messageIncomming":
    var message = data.message.text;
    var firstname = data.message.from.first_name;
    var lastname = data.message.from.last_name;
    var name = firstname + " " + lastname;
    $('#messages').prepend('<div id="message"><p>'+message+'</p><p id="name">'+name+'</p><a href="#" class="button" data-bind="click: replay">click</a></div>'); 

        self.replay = function(){
            console.log('test');
        }

    break;

    default:
        }

        return;

}

}
```

Comment: If you use knockout in your project, you should use it for *all* DOM modifications. I.e.: use the `template`, `with`, `if` and `foreach` bindings to dynamically inject pieces of HTML. Use the `text` binding to inject your `name` and `message`. Did you work your way through the knockout tutorials yet?

Comment: Won't, and can't work. You should not change DOM elements while binding is in effect.